# Deploy IIS Website with CloudFormation template

Tags: c#, aws-cloudformation

I have a Visual Studio (C#) deployment package (.zip) that I have pushed up to my S3 storage.

I want to run my CloudFormation script and have it create an instance of an IIS server (I have the script for this) and then deploy the Visual Studio web site to it from the S3 storage.

I'm looking for an example of the temple json that would do that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a template that does something similar to what you are looking for.  Below is a template that I use.  It may be more than you need, because it has an auto scaling group, but it will get you started.  Basically, you need the IAM user to interact with cloud formation.  The script in the UserData starts cf-init, which does the stuff in the metadata section.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Autoscaling for .net Web application.",
    "Parameters": {
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "m1.small",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "m1.small",
                "m1.medium",
                "m1.large",
                "m1.xlarge",
                "m2.xlarge",
                "m2.2xlarge",
                "m2.4xlarge",
                "c1.medium",
                "c1.xlarge",
                "cc1.4xlarge",
                "cc2.8xlarge",
                "cg1.4xlarge"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
        "IamInstanceProfile": {
            "Description": "Name of IAM Profile that will be used by instances to access AWS Services",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "YourProfileName"
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow access to the instances",
            "Default": "yourkeypair",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "SpotPriceBid": {
            "Description": "Max bid price of spot instances",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": ".06"
        },
        "DeployS3Bucket": {
            "Description": "The S3 Bucket where deploy files are stored",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "ApplicationBucket"
        },
        "DeployWebS3Key": {
            "Description": "The zip file that holds the website",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "Application.zip"
        },
        "DNSHostedZone": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "example.com.",
            "AllowedPattern": "^[\\w\\.]*\\.$",
            "ConstraintDescription": "DNSDomain must end with '.'"
        },
        "DNSSubDomain": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "yoursubdomain"
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "RegionToAMIMap": {
            "us-east-1": {
                "AMI": "ami-1234567"
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "IAMUser": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::User",
            "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "Policies": [{
                        "PolicyName": "webuser",
                        "PolicyDocument": {
                            "Statement": [{
                                    "Sid": "Stmt1353842250430",
                                    "Action": [
                                        "s3:GetObject"
                                    ],
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Resource": [
                                        "arn:aws:s3:::HelgaDogWeb*/*"
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    "Sid": "Stmt1353842327065",
                                    "Action": [
                                        "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource"
                                    ],
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Resource": [
                                        "*"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "IAMUserAccessKey": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
            "Properties": {
                "UserName": {
                    "Ref": "IAMUser"
                }
            }
        },
        "WebSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Enable Access From Elastic Load Balancer.",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "443",
                        "ToPort": "443",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "WebLoadBalancer",
                                "SourceSecurityGroup.OwnerAlias"
                            ]
                        },
                        "SourceSecurityGroupName": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "WebLoadBalancer",
                                "SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "WebLoadBalancer",
                                "SourceSecurityGroup.OwnerAlias"
                            ]
                        },
                        "SourceSecurityGroupName": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "WebLoadBalancer",
                                "SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "WebLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "Listeners": [{
                        "InstancePort": "443",
                        "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS",
                        "LoadBalancerPort": "443",
                        "Protocol": "HTTPS",
                        "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:server-certificate/example"
                    }
                ],
                "AvailabilityZones": {
                    "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                },
                "HealthCheck": {
                    "HealthyThreshold": "3",
                    "Interval": "30",
                    "Target": "HTTP:80/healthcheck.aspx",
                    "Timeout": 8,
                    "UnhealthyThreshold": "2"
                }
            }
        },
        "WebAsSpotLaunchConfiguration": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                    "config": {
                        "sources": {
                            "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "/",
                                    [
                                        "http://s3.amazonaws.com", {
                                            "Ref": "DeployS3Bucket"
                                        }, {
                                            "Ref": "DeployWebS3Key"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "commands": {
                            "1-set-appPool-identity": {
                                "command": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='DefaultAppPool'].processModel.identityType:LocalSystem",
                                "waitAfterCompletion": "0"
                            },
                            "2-add-http-binding": {
                                "command": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd set site /site.name:\"Default Web Site\" /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:']",
                                "waitAfterCompletion": "0"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                    "S3AccessCreds": {
                        "type": "S3",
                        "accessKeyId": {
                            "Ref": "IAMUserAccessKey"
                        },
                        "secretKey": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "IAMUserAccessKey",
                                "SecretAccessKey"
                            ]
                        },
                        "buckets": [{
                                "Ref": "DeployS3Bucket"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "ImageId": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "RegionToAMIMap", {
                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                        },
                        "AMI"
                    ]
                },
                "IamInstanceProfile": {
                    "Ref": "IamInstanceProfile"
                },
                "SecurityGroups": [{
                        "Ref": "WebSecurityGroup"
                    }
                ],
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "SpotPrice": {
                    "Ref": "SpotPriceBid"
                },
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "<script>\n",
                                "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Amazon\\cfn-bootstrap\\cfn-init.exe\" -v -s ", {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                " -r WebAsSpotLaunchConfiguration ",
                                " --access-key ", {
                                    "Ref": "IAMUserAccessKey"
                                },
                                " --secret-key ", {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "IAMUserAccessKey",
                                        "SecretAccessKey"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "\n",
                                "</script>"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "WebAsSpotGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZones": {
                    "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                },
                "HealthCheckGracePeriod": "120",
                "HealthCheckType": "EC2",
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "WebAsSpotLaunchConfiguration"
                },
                "LoadBalancerNames": [{
                        "Ref": "WebLoadBalancer"
                    }
                ],
                "MaxSize": "20",
                "MinSize": "1",
                "DesiredCapacity": "1"
            }
        },
        "WebAsSpotScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "PercentChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebAsSpotGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "420",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "200"
            }
        },
        "WebAsSpotScaleDownPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebAsSpotGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
            }
        },
        "WebAsSpotScaleUpAlarm": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "60",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "1",
                "Threshold": "75",
                "AlarmActions": [{
                        "Ref": "WebAsSpotScaleUpPolicy"
                    }
                ],
                "Dimensions": [{
                        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "WebAsSpotGroup"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "WebAsSpotScaleDownAlarm": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "60",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "50",
                "AlarmActions": [{
                        "Ref": "WebAsSpotScaleDownPolicy"
                    }
                ],
                "Dimensions": [{
                        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "WebAsSpotGroup"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "DNSRecord": {
            "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
            "Properties": {
                "HostedZoneName": {
                    "Ref": "DNSHostedZone"
                },
                "Comment": "VPN Host. Created by Cloud Formation.",
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        ".",
                        [{
                                "Ref": "DNSSubDomain"
                            }, {
                                "Ref": "DNSHostedZone"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "Type": "CNAME",
                "TTL": "150",
                "ResourceRecords": [{
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "WebLoadBalancer",
                            "CanonicalHostedZoneName"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "DependsOn": "WebLoadBalancer"
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin, that looks very extensive.

Comment: It's not that complex when you get into it, but it is a bit difficult to explain in words.  The real trouble is getting the JSON syntax right.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using an instance that already has IIS installed and https enabled. The instance has the http binding removed on purpose so to be added by the cloud formation script.  This was so that the load balancers health check wouldn't see the instance as up until cfn-init finished its work.

Comment: Is this KeyName something i should have already or something I use later?

Comment: The SSLCert. where do you keep that? I've just requested our from our IT department. So I was going to look at putting it in a similar place

Comment: You have to upload it to the IAM service. There are some how tos out there.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it myself, but this post, on the AWS site,  [Using Amazon CloudFront with ASP.NET Apps](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1L748XAK9737T/Using-Amazon-CloudFront-with-ASP-NET-Apps) maybe somewhere to start.