# How to create an IamInstanceProfile in CloudFormation ::LaunchConfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an CloudFormation script (courtesy of Edwin) [CloudFormationScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930006/deploy-iis-website-with-cloudformation-template)

IamInstanceProfile = aws:iam::093026445011:user/qsw.internal

From the script

```
...

"IamInstanceProfile" : {
                "Ref" : "IamInstanceProfile"
            },

...
```

when I run it I am getting:

```
Invalid IamInstanceProfile: arn:aws:iam::093026445011:user/qsw.internal

The Type is

AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration

Logical ID

WebAsSpotLaunchConfiguration
```

Ref to the documentation on this field:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-iaminstanceprofile

I've got a lot of permissions on the account i've asked it to be assigned and I've used the ARN ID (aws:iam::093026445011:user/qsw.internal).

What areas should I be looking at to fix this?

Comment: I've found the issue may be with the role I was using. I changed the role and it now runs through. I'll update the post once I find out what is wrong with the role

Answer (score 0):

This parameter takes the Role Name of the IAM Role as found in the console --> https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#roles.

Comment: Are you passing the parameter as specified here --> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html ?

Comment: I don't think i am. Could you show me an example please?

Comment: No, I usually deploy through Visual Studio, which takes care of this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable debug logging For example in boto - python aws sdk, they provide this option

```
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2(debug=2)
```

Which will enable the detailed logging of the HTTP requests