# AWS cloudformation template or bootstrap script help required

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am looking for cloudformation template which can create below environment.

```
1. A VPC which contains a single public subnet
2. A Windows-based webserver instance set in an auto-scaling group to scale to 2 instances across 2 availability zones
3. Have the webservers install/host their webhosting software on launch (UserData), create a sample “hello world” index.html page to demonstrate with.
4. An Elastic Load Balancer which routes traffic to any healthy webservers created in step 2 and acts as a single DNS
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFormation has some great [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.html), [samples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-sample-templates.html) and [quick starts](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) to get you going. Amazon even have [a tutorial on spinning up an autoscaling groups with EC2 instance and ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/example-templates-autoscaling.html) (Linux webserver but it's a good place to start).

There are also some good answers on [StackOverflow for similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930006/deploy-iis-website-with-cloudformation-template).